# MySQL CBC Encryption and Storing Initialization Vector

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

I'm working on a HIPAA project and it has come to my attention that I need to encrypt all column level data that does or may contain private health information. That said I'm looking to use the AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT with MySQL in block_encryption_mode=aes-256-cbc. It looks like I need to have an IV (initialization vector) uniquely for each row in the table. I will need this same IV to both encrypt and decrypt. Should I just store it in a column in the database or something else?

Also for the column type is it better to use varbinary/blob or HEX the encrypted results and put it into a varchar/text?

Any other suggestions are most welcome to keep the data as secure as possible.

Comment: if you're storing the key with the encrypted data, you've accomplished nothing. it's the equivalent of a bank vault with the lock's combination written beside the lock. encryption isn't just something you can check off on a marketing checklist. there's a whole pile of OTHER stuff that has to be deal with, to the point that the actual mechanics of enc-/de-crypting and storage of that cyphertext is the least of your problems.

Comment: I would never store the key with the data...that's just silly. CBC takes a key (to be kept in the web app never in the DB) and an IV. The IV should be random and different by record.

Comment: @MarcB the IV (Initialization Vector) does not need to be secret and usually isn't. The IV is not the encryption key.

Comment: Was thinking to keep the key outside of the application and encrypted in a file tucked away some place not obvious with a common extension

Answer (score 0):

Store is iv in a column, it does not need to be secret.

I would use a varbinary/blob instead of hex encoding the data.

Note: Base64 is a better option that hex, there is less storage overhead.

Addressing @Marc somewhat: How will the encryption key be protected? How good is the server protection and admin access.

Comment: Server is planned to be in a locked closet with cooling provided of course. We were planning on disk encryption as well as encryption at the column level. As for access, it will be locked down and secure with a key and deadbolt, and only two people will have access to that room. We were planning to have a firewall/router in front of the web head to block access and just opening 443 to the web/database server.

As for the key itself, It'd be contained in a file located somewhere on the server and the encryption key would be encrypted itself via web app.